# I use electron11 vue-cli3 ,node-loader not work. who can hlep me?

Tags: webpack, electron, vue-cli-3

node:14.15.4
npm:6.14.10
electron:11.2.2
in vue.config.js
[vue.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBf1z.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoKsO.png)

```
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".vue", ".json", ".ts", ".less"],
      alias: {
        "@": resolve("src")
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.node$/, loader: 'node-loader' }
      ]
    }
  },
  // chainWebpack: config => {
    // config.module.rule('ts')
    // .use('ts-loader')
    // .loader('ts-loader')
    // .end()
    // .rule(/\.node$/)
    // .use('node-loader')
    // .loader('node-loader')
    // .end()
  // },
```

error  in ./build/Release/addon.node

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: Please specify the issue and what you want to do. Also you could paste the code that you have tried in the question as that would be helpful for someone giving the answer to you.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya thanks,I have posted the image, I want import the native file (*.node),I set the node-loader config in vue.config.js ,but there is an error for me